P trap leaking at connection to wall pipe
So my sink in my bathroom as been leaking for a bit. I finally was able to borrow a pipe wrench from somebody and tried to tighten it.  Still leaking.
I took off the J portion and noticed it looks a little worn out/corroded on the edge, where the pipes connect. Could this be my problem?  If so, is it possible to get this one piece and what would it be called?
I know nothing about plumbing and would like to not permanently have a bucket under my sink.

The pipe you describe is called a P-trap. They are usually made of plastic or metal and can corrode and leak over time. The parts are inexpensive and an easy fix for a diyer. If you want to give it a shot we can help here. There are also good tutorials on YouTube but also some questionable ones as well. Also, pictures can help us to help you.

do not use wrench, those are hand tied. open it up and find a plastic seal, clean and replace it

I've added some pictures, also it would have been physically impossible for my to undue with my hands as it was on really tight

I've been watching some videos online. I'm going to try to go to a hardware store to ask someone for help. But when I google the j piece it comes with new connectors?  I have zero clue how to take anything else off of this because at the wall there's that flare cover. And it won't move.

This may help: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257051/fixing-a-leaking-p-trap-when-the-outlet-pipe-has-a-lip-on-it?rq=1

Ended up taking a closer look. Looks like there a hair line crack in the lip of the wall pipe. Going to just get my landlord to fix it
